# Allowing divs to layer above flash content

Tags: flash, wmode

I've built myself some flash content for my website, but I need some divs to be visible over the top of the flash. I've read that making the WMODE=transparent should work, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out where I need to place it within my code.

Firstly, is this correct? Should making WMODE=transparent help me layer my divs over the top? and secondly...

Could someone explain if I have param name="wmode" value="transparent" in the right place in this code or not, or is there something else required for this to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash
/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','680','height','370','src','slideshow-
load','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download
/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','slideshow-load' ); //end AC code

</script><noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" 
width="680" height="370">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="movie" value="slideshow-load.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="slideshow-load.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave
/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
width="680" height="370"></embed>
  </object>
</noscript>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it!

I published the flash as an HTML file with window mode set to transparent (in flash) then I copied the code straight from the automatically created file into mine and it's working great. If anyone is interested, this is the code.

```
<script language="javascript">
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        'width', '680',
        'height', '370',
        'src', 'index-slideshow',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'true',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'showall',
        'wmode', 'transparent',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'index-slideshow',
        'bgcolor', '#000000',
        'name', 'index-slideshow',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'index-slideshow',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
}
</script>
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="680" height="370" id="index-slideshow" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="index-slideshow.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />   <embed src="index-slideshow.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#000000" width="680" height="370" name="index-slideshow" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</noscript>
```

Panic over :)